# Any Chance to make CodeMirror play on Android Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, codemirror

I understand CodeMirror has issues on mobile and behavior varies with extensions in use.

However, for me it seems pretty much unusable everywhere I encounter it on Android. Have a look at [Kotlin Koans](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Hello,%20world!/Task.kt) and try the Backspace key. Amongst other things, I get gobbledygock and a bunch of newlines.

I did not find a single way around this. Tried two devices (OnePlus 3T and Pixel C) running Android 7 and 8 using on-screen keyboards or bluetooth physical ones. The results are pretty much the same.

This seems pretty odd and I am surprised nobody (Google?) is stepping in to fix it.

I'd like to use an Android device for basic (CodeMirror-based) coding, and I'd very much appreciate a suggestion to get around this annoyance. :)

Thanks

[Code Editor inserts a new line above current line on every keypress](https://github.com/Codewars/codewars.com/issues/693)
[Android native app using WebView, backspace doesn't work properly](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/1196)

Comment: It works for me, see the [MGit](https://github.com/maks/MGit) app whose editor is based on CodeMirror.

Comment: Did you find the answer ? I am having similar issues. It overwrites the character every time I try to write a new character. So, ultimately I can write only character in the entire editor